# Shadows not working on FabricJS

Tags: css, fabricjs

I have updated FabricJS version 1.5 to 1.6(beta), then the text shadow effects does not work now. Here is my function. How to fix this issue?

```
$('#text-shadow-set').change(function (){
if(isText()) {
    if(this.checked) {
        var tmp = $('#text-shadow-offset-slider').slider('option','value');
        var shadVal = (tmp==''||tmp==0) ? 20 : tmp;
        currentElement.setShadow({
            color: '#000',
            blur: 5,
            offsetX: shadVal,
            offsetY: shadVal
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
    } else {
        currentElement.setShadow(null);
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Where are you defining "currentElement"?

Comment: @DarrylHebbes currentElement defined within myCode. It means current selected object on canvas. The shadow effect works with fabricJS 1.5. I think problem occurs with 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

Text and shadows seem to work fine. Check the demo below:

```
var text = new fabric.Text('Text with Shadow', {
    left: 50,
    top: 150,
    fill: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: 'black',
});

text.setShadow({
    color: 'black',
    blur: 5,
    offsetX: 10,
    offsetY: 10,
    opacity: 0.5,
});
canvas.add(text);
canvas.renderAll();
```

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var text = new fabric.Text('Text with Shadow', {
 left: 50,
 top: 150,
 fill: 'red',
 strokeWidth: 1,
 stroke: 'black',
});

text.setShadow({
    color: 'black',
    blur: 5,
    offsetX: 10,
    offsetY: 10,
    opacity: 0.5,
});
canvas.add(text);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```